# Redirect to next episode when finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to revive a web page but I don't have the scripts that when a episode is over the website redirects the user from from ex. moviepage.com/true-blood/s01e03 to moviepage.com/true-blood/s01e04,

Is it javascript or do i have to do it with a server side script?

Comment: That's pretty vague. But depending on which video player you're using, and whether or not it has an API available that you can hook into (something like a video onComplete function), you could check for that, and then re-direct.

Comment: I am gonna try to make my own videoplayer, i'm gonna try the oncomplete function. Thanks for the tip :)